# Blazor Mobile Bindings with WebView as URL

Tags: blazor

Using dotnet core 3.1 and Mobile Blazor Bindings templates.

i don't see any sample of WebView component in Blazor Mobile Bindings online right now.
Is it possible to show any URL in a Mobile Blazor Binding application?

Would be great if someone has a hint.

```
<Frame CornerRadius="10" BackgroundColor="Color.LightBlue">

<StackLayout Orientation="StackOrientation.Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="LayoutOptions.Center">

    <Button OnClick="@IncrementCount">Gehe zu Store</Button>

    <Label Text="@("Der Store wurde " + count + " besucht.")"
           FontAttributes="FontAttributes.Bold"
           VerticalTextAlignment="TextAlignment.Center" />

</StackLayout>
```

Here I want to have a component where I want to show e.g. "https://google.de"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of control that doesn't exist yet, it is still experimental, so don't use it right now. But for your problem you can use **BlazorWebView** in July update.
In BlazorWebView you can set any HTML content, that content will be written in Razor files and included in the project.
Follow this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/hybrid-blazor-apps-in-mobile-blazor-bindings-july-update/)